# How to differentiate you are or you were from you're?

Tags: word-usage

I need clarification on this sentence.

I'm asking this to someone (in written):

> *What is the problem **you're** facing with C++?*

My question is, How do you get that whether its **you are** or **you were** ?

Comment: Your question is ungrammatical.  It's either "What problem are you facing" or "What problem were you facing" there is no oppportunity for a contraction here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the false premise that the "so-called ambiguous question" is grammatical.

Comment: Actually if the conversation went like this, A: "I just can't figure out this problem I'm facing with C++"  B:'What problem you're facing with C++?"  I could make it grammatical but I doubt that's how it was being used in the OP.

Comment: I might answer, 'Half my code was inherited from someone who didn't use *const* correctly and the compiler wont let me call any of those functions until I basically rewrite the whole thing with *consts* everywhere."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner is asking us to decipher a bad grammatical construction, which he/she uses everyday but should not be using at all.

Comment: That is, "uses every day"

Comment: @BlessedGeek, You should not go in deep with this, I've updated my question as Jim proposed already. Wait, I already told him that I'm not a native english speaker thus it may possible that there's problem in other part (other than question) of the question. So be polite and don't encourage other to stop giving answers to the people like me. If someone found that I'm wrong at my grammar then they're free to come towards me with my mistake. Yes, they shall point me to my mistakes and allow me to learn something from that.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/everyday. http://grammarist.com/usage/everyday-every-day/

Comment: @Araucaria- My comment was against an earlier version of the question which was, "What problem you're facing with C++?"

Comment: @Jim Ah, I see. Sorry! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if it was a problem or if it is a (current) problem.  So you would write 'what is the problem you're facing with C++?' or if it is no longer an issue, 'what was the problem you were facing with C++?'.

Comment: You mean that, we would never write `you were` to `you're` ? Is this true?

Comment: "you were" doesnt shorten to "you're".

Comment: If I asked it like this, `What's the problem you're facing with C++?` then what would say about it?

Comment: I may well say 'I am not facing any problem with C++ now.  I had problems with it during my college days'!

Comment: No no, you didn't get what I mean, I'm asking about this sentence and not your reply for it. `What's the problem you're facing with C++?` Is this correct sentence to ask?

Comment: Of course, it is a correct sentence to ask 'verbally'.  If you write it in words (put pen to paper), then it will be understood as 'what is the problem you are facing with C++?' (current problem).

Comment: Why would you even bother to answer a question that is thoroughly unnecessary, a question wanting you to interpret a grammar that does not exist in normal English usage?

Comment: @BlessedGeek I don't get what you're saying. Arwe you saying that "what problem's are you facing **with C++**" is ungrammatical?

Answer (score 3):

It is “you are,” always. “You’re” is a contraction for “you are,” not “you were.” See [Does "you're" also qualify as a valid contraction for "you were"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20581/does-youre-also-qualify-as-a-valid-contraction-for-you-were).

Comment: So whenever I would see like `you're`, `we're` then it should be `you are` and `we are` respectively?

Comment: Yes, _you're_ means _you are_, and _we're_ means _we are_.

Comment: Ok, one last question if I asked it like this, `What's the problem you're facing with C++?` then what would say about it?

Comment: You should say: What problem are you facing/having with etc.? (present) What problem did you face/have with etc.? (past)

Comment: Perfect, easy and succinct- answers the OP, plus one!

Answer (score 1):

Contractions are for speed, so there's no point in using them for the past tense.